# Cmake add include paths to clang

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, clang, include-path

I am currently developing in C++ with Atom from GitHub. I found the addon `autocomplete-clang` which adds an autocomplete feature to Atom.
My problem is, that I use cmake to build my program and I also use a project structure like this:

```
- Sensors
-- src
-- inc
- LowLevel
-- src
-- inc
- System
-- src
-- inc
```

I only use `#include "someHeaderFromSystem.h"` in the `someSourceFileFromLowLevel.cxx` in my code. This means, that clang does not find the include files.

Is there a way to tell clang where to find the files, which does not change any global system variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` to the `CMakeLists.txt` file which generates the file `compile_commands.json`. With this file the `include` directives are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, that's what [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) is made for.

It specifies additional include directories the compiler will search in.

---

If you have a *CMakeLists.txt* in Sensors, LowLevel, System, you can add this in each:

```
include_directories(inc)
```

If you have only a main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(Sensors/inc LowLevel/inc System/inc)
```

Comment: Well I did that. If I user `cmake .` command it generates the make files. Those also work as expected. But during editing in Atom the background linter which depents on clang does not find the right include directories.

Comment: I see, so it's more an atom-related issue. Have you checked if `compile_commands.json` is created? If not, you can enable it by `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` for your cmake build.